# How to create a "help / information bubble" with netbean

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a GUI with netbean, and I've created a tool bar with different icon. What I want to do is this: When you mouse over one of the button I want a little text bubble to appear with text that I will have specified.

I've been searching the web for a while, and all I could find was something about this package: "org.openide.awt" wich contains (in theory from what I've read) NotificationDisplayer.

If this thing really works with java and netbeans well, I can't get it to work. All I need to know is does this package is actually netbean/java compatible, or better, if there is a simpler way to display a text bubble.

Comment: Isn't this just a Java problem, regardless of the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool tip?

The [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText(java.lang.String)) API has support for that.

Check if this is what you need:

[How to Use Tool Bars](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

ie:
[image]

Comment: I'm glad. Since this is your first time in SO I would suggest you to mark my answer as accepted ;) :")